# Loop through objects and show duplicated values once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, object

I'm not sure how to title this problem correctly.
I've got an object and within that object a few of the values are duplicated, I want to show those only once and carry on looping through the object and show everything else.

```
   const teachingClasses = [
    {
        subject: 1,
        name: "maths addition",
        description: "sums"
    },
    {
        subject: 1,
        name: "maths subtraction",
        description: "subtract"
    },
    {
        subject: 2,
        name: "geo",
        description: "maps"
    },
    {
        subject: 3,
        name: "history",
        description: "kings"
    },
]
```

The desired outcome will be as follows:

```
1
maths addition
sums
maths subtraction
subtract

2
geo
maps

3
history
kings
```

My plan was to somehow get the subject and the index and match them on the next subject and index, if subjects don't match then display the subject.

This is what i have so far

```
{teachingClasses.map((subjectPackage, index) => (
{[subjectPackage.subject, index] !== [subjectPackage.subject, index] + 1 
&& subjectPackage.subject !== subjectPackage.subject + 1
              ? console.log(subjectPackage)
              : ""}
))}
```

That's not working as I'm not sure how to compare the subjects.

Any help getting the desired effect or if there's a better wasy of doing this, it will be appreciated.

Comment: *I've got an object and within that object a few of the values are duplicated* What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: *match them on the next subject and index*, When you say `next` then do you mean the very next element or can be anywhere onwards?

Answer (score 0):

First, group the data, Then print.

**Note:** Please be more specific to get optimized code.

```js
const teachingClasses = [
    {
        subject: 1,
        name: "maths addition",
        description: "sums"
    },
    {
        subject: 1,
        name: "maths subtraction",
        description: "subtract"
    },
    {
        subject: 2,
        name: "geo",
        description: "maps"
    },
    {
        subject: 3,
        name: "history",
        description: "kings"
    },
];


const formattedData = [];

teachingClasses.forEach(teachingClass => {
  if (formattedData[teachingClass.subject]) {
    formattedData[teachingClass.subject].push(teachingClass);
  } else {
    formattedData[teachingClass.subject] = [teachingClass];
  }
});


formattedData.forEach((formattedClass,index) => {
  
  console.log(index);
  
  formattedClass.forEach(c => {
    console.log(c.name);
    console.log(c.description);
  });
});
```

Comment: *I am not sure what you are trying to achieve*. If you're not sure then how you come up with this answer...

Comment: @decpk He provided the result that he expected.

Comment: @deckpk This is exactly what I wanted.  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're simply trying to group by the subject and then output the results of each group. You can group using `reduce` and then simply iterate the lists:

```js
const teachingClasses = [
    {
        subject: 1,
        name: "maths addition",
        description: "sums"
    },
    {
        subject: 1,
        name: "maths subtraction",
        description: "subtract"
    },
    {
        subject: 2,
        name: "geo",
        description: "maps"
    },
    {
        subject: 3,
        name: "history",
        description: "kings"
    },
]

const grouped = teachingClasses.reduce( (acc, i) => {
    const arr = acc[i.subject] || [];
    arr.push(i);
    acc[i.subject] = arr;
    return acc;
},{});

Object.entries(grouped).forEach( ([subject,values]) => {
    console.log(subject);
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
        console.log(values[i].name);
        console.log(values[i].description);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is great.  Thank you